# What is the meaning of pull strategy when creating a branch with egit?

Tags: eclipse, git, egit, jgit

In EGit when I got to `Team > Switch to > New branch` I end up with the dialog box below. What is the meaning of the various pull strategies listed on this dialog box?

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Take a look at this from **[here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Branch_Creation_Dialog)** :

[image]

From the above link :

> The "Pull Strategy" group is only visible when a branch is selected in
>   the combo and allows to override the default setup for the "upstream
>   configuration" which is helpful when fetching and pushing, but
>   particularly when pulling. Depending on the selected option the
>   following configuration can be chosen:
>
> **Rebase**: When pulling, new changes will be fetched from upstream and the remote tracking branch will be updated. Then the current local branch will be rebased onto the updated remote tracking branch
>
> **Merge**: When pulling, the changes will be fetched from upstream and the remote tracking branch will be updated. Then the current local branch will be merged with the new changes. This is the default if the new branch is based on a remote tracking branch (but this default may be overridden by specific repository configuration)
>
> **None**: When pulling, no specific upstream configuration will be done for the new branch; however, if a default remote exists (a remote
>   with name "origin", pull will try to use the configuration of this
>   remote; this is the default if the new branch is not based on a remote
>   tracking branch

### Command Line Equivalents

I *think*, the command line equivalent's of the above would be as follows:

**Rebase**

```
git fetch   //This updates the remote-tracking-branch such as remotes/origin/master    
git rebase remotes/origin/master
```

**Merge**

```
git fetch   // This updates the remote-tracking-branch such as remotes/origin/master
git merge remotes/origin/master
```

Having written that, my knowledge of GIT does not make me confident of the above.

Comment: FWIW, since this is a *pull strategy*, it would be run for the branch you are on, so no need for `checkout`.  Also, `git pull` is a shortcut (if you will) for the *merge* strategy and `git pull --rebase` is a shortcut for the rebase strategy.

Comment: I would suggest you use rebase as default and do no-rebase from command line only when you have large merge commits.